# Custom agreement for Google Cloud Translator API attribution

Tags: google-translate, attribution

We are planning to use Google Cloud Translator API for software and website translations for the company. I'm aware of the attributions requirement but wanting to find out if it is possible to have a custom agreement with Google on the attribution requirements especially in the software.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to read the [attribution requirements](https://cloud.google.com/translate/attribution) and the [terms of service](https://cloud.google.com/terms) before contacting Google.

Then fill [this form](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/translation-attiribution/) to ask for this specific information. You could explain why and what you want to change the, let's say, "default" conditions.